# How to modifying and apply an already defined class on Java

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I want modify and apply an already defined class.

I changed the "Target" class below using ASM, but I don't know how to apply it at runtime.

How do I make the "newTarget.a()" and "newTarget.b()" call the methods of the changed class?

```
package asm;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;

import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ASM5;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Target target = new Target();
        target.a();
        target.b();

        ClassReader reader = new ClassReader("asm.Main$Target");
        ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(0);
        ClassVisitor visitor = new TestClassVisitor(ASM5, writer);

        reader.accept(visitor, 0);

        byte[] transformed = writer.toByteArray();

        // Apply byte[] transformed

        Target newTarget = new Target();
        newTarget.a();
        newTarget.b();
    }

    static class Target {
        private void a() {
            System.out.println("first method");
        }

        private void b() {
            System.out.println("second method");
        }
    }

    static class TestClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {
        public TestClassVisitor(int i, ClassVisitor classVisitor) {
            super(i, classVisitor);
        }

        @Override
        public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int i, String s, String s1, String s2, String[] strings) {
            MethodVisitor visitor = super.visitMethod(i, s, s1, s2, strings);
            if (!s.equals("<init>")) {
                return visitor;
            }
            return new TestMethodVisitor(api, visitor);
        }
    }

    static class TestMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {
        public TestMethodVisitor(int i, MethodVisitor methodVisitor) {
            super(i, methodVisitor);
        }

        @Override
        public void visitCode() {
            super.visitCode();
            super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            super.visitLdcInsn("transformed method");
            super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        }

        @Override
        public void visitEnd() {
            super.visitEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to extend the Target class with another and override those methods a and b to do something else? i'm confused on your wording of the question

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Sorry.. I used google translator. What I want is to override the class that I changed to ASM.

Comment: Changing an already defined class can only be done by an agent via the `Instrumentation` API or JVMTI.